# How can QuickTest Pro use portable libraries, resources, etc.?

Tags: relative-path, qtp

I am setting up testing with QuickTest Pro in an automated environment where I call the test from a vbscript.  I need these tests to reference libraries, but I don't want to rely on an absolute path for those libraries (e.g. `C:\myLibrary`).  I **can** use relative libraries (e.g. `..\myLibrary`) but how do I get QTP to recognize these libraries like this?  I'm not a QTP expert, but I need to make these tests completely portable including resources, and any other external parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a function library in Resources tab of Settings dialog box. When you add a reference to the script, it will show you a dialog box where in you can choose whether you want the path to be relative or absolute. I remember you have to click Yes for the script to take relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Folow as Budda suggested
Also if you have some common resources outside your test folder whose hierarchical position can change frequently you will need to locate the absolute path from Options>Folder Path settings and set it for the first-time on every test machine you plan to execute the tests on. As this setting is QTP Application specific and not test specific they need not be changed unless the hierarchy undergoes a change.